# Validate uniqueness of street address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a general question: If I want to validate the uniqueness of a street address and want to make sure that semantic equalities like "drive" and "dr" are counted as the same thing in the validate, how/where would I declare such equalities for the validation?

Comment: In the model? Where you expecting a more specific answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalize those addresses somehow. I recommend the geocoder gem with google.

Comment: google geocoder is not bad, but it fails badly in many rural areas (speaking from experience).

Comment: Not as bad as the Philippines post office would (also from experience) :)

Comment: Ok, so I am thinking something like, user enters an address, use geocoder to compute the lat & lon, use the lat & lon to return Google's address (thus normalizing it according to Google's conventions) and then performing the save?

Answer (score 1):

This is a non trivial problem.  You aren't going to solve it with a list of adhoc rules about normalizing addresses.  If you want to do it well, you should find a USPS certified [Coding Accuracy Support System (CASS) library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_Accuracy_Support_System) and use it to normalize your addresses.

Comment: OP never actually mentions that these are US addresses

Comment: @pguardiario True enough.  I'm sure address normalization is tough in non-US regions too and I would recommend the postal services of other countries as the goto authority for how to do it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validates :address, :uniqueness => true` in your model.

To ensure semantic equalities your best shot is to do some cleanup before save and transform all "dr" in to "drive", all 2 spaces into 1 space, and stuff like that.

But I doubt you will be successful with this! Why don't you just use postal code, zip code or whatever is called?? That's supposed to be a uniq identifier for an address so why don't you use it?

Comment: In the USA, ZIP+4 codes don't uniquely identify an address. If you tilt your head and squint, you might be able to claim they uniquely identify a mail delivery "area". But "area" might range from a single house to several acres of apartments or shopping centers.